# Reinstantiating Instance Variables - a design query

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I am currently using the paradigm I'm about to describe below in my application and it works, so It's not a big problem; however, I would like to know if I'm breaking some kind of rule with this pattern.

I am using ARC.

I have an application which presents a modal viewController. It has a table view on it.

I then have an "add" button which allows me to enter some data into the table view.

Pressing add, pops up a little dialog box created from a  UIView with many textFields. - Each textField is an instance variable.

I'm alloc initing the textField instance variables when my add method gets called.

My question is: Is it OK to call this add method on my viewController which instantiates the instance variables and uses them, and then later, call the same method again which would be calling alloc init on instance variables that were already allocd and inited the last time the method was called.

Thus calling alloc init on the same ivars without niling them first - i'm also using ARC?

Something like this pseudocode:

**.h**

```
@property UITextField *textField;
```

**.m**

```
@synthesize textField;



(void) someMethod {

textField = [[UITextField alloc] init] 
[textField doSomethingElse]

}
```

**LATER**

Some method is called over and over again.

Should I instead alloc init all the textfields, and just add and remove them from my UIView in the add method?

Thanks,
Regards,
John

Comment: If you are reusing the text fields it's pretty unnecessary to be creating them over and over each time that method is called don't you think?

Comment: Sure so how can I avoid creating them over and over, just alloc init in viewDidLoad perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition you can't call `alloc` on existing instances. What you're doing is causing the old instances to be destroyed and creating new instances to replace them. There is nothing necessarily wrong with this, but it could be quite wasteful and, depending on how hard it is to create those instances, time consuming.

Comment: OK, so each time alloc init is called again on an ivar ARC would destroy the old and replace it? so there is no leak?.... this sounds ok, would a more elegant way to do this be: alloc init ivars in viewdid load and then just add and remove them as subviews from my uiview in my add method?

Comment: What is wasteful? It would be wasteful to keep things that you do not need around in memory.

Comment: @Mundi, it is wasteful to recreate an existing item if you can just update it instead. If you don't need it any more then it should be destroyed if it won't be required for some time and recreating it is expensive.

Comment: Not sure this is the case. If he is pushing a modal view controller, the standard process is to dealloc and recreated. If he just wants to make views disappear and reappear (a rather strange setup) it would be simpler to just hide and show them.

Answer (score 1):

When your add controller is dismissed ARC should take care of deallocating all the instance variables. So there is no harm in recreating them when you need them again.

Comment: is there a better way to create them only once but still have them valid for the whole class?

Comment: Actually, it is better to forget about the ivars when you don't need them any more and recreate them later once you need them again. Otherwise you would keep stuff in memory that is not useful. You can cache things you are going to need later if there is a performance issue, but surely this is not the case in your setup.

Comment: If I don't use ivars how can I extract the textField text in another part of my application?  If I alloc init the ivars in viewdidLoad and then just add them and remove them from the uiview is that a good solution?

Comment: See my comment to the other answer.